# Express-session: req.session.variable re-assignment not effective between two routes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am putting in place a very simple app where a logged in user can search and book train journeys, via Express, MongDB, Mongoose and Express-session. The selected journeys are temporarily saved in req.session.order variable (which I understand is global across all routes) and once confirmed, A-stored in DB as sub-documents of the user and B-req.session.order is assigned to an empty array so that the user can continue booking/selecting other journeys. The problem is after the confirmation, when going back to home page, the req.session.order array is not empty and still contains previously selected journeys that have already been confirmed and stored.

As you can see in the code below, I am just console logging the req.session.order at the end of the /confirm route instruction which returns empty array as expected but when going back to home page, the console still logs previously pushed journey._id.

Feel that I am missing something with express-session, thanks a lot for your help

```js
// (req.session.order are initialized to [] in singnin/signup routes before redirecting to home page)

/* GET confirmation page. */
router.get('/order', async function(req, res, next) {
  var bookedJourney = await journeyModel.findOne({ _id: req.query.id });
  **req.session.order.push(bookedJourney);**
  res.render('confirmation', {order: req.session.order, reformatTime: reformatTime, reformatDate: reformatDate});
});

/* POST add selected journeys to trip list */
router.post('/confirm', async function(req, res, next) {
  var currentUser = await userModel.findOne({ email: req.session.user.email });
  req.session.order.forEach((order) => {
    currentUser.journey.push(order._id);
  });
  await currentUser.save();
  **req.session.order = []; // This returns empty array as expected**
  console.log(req.session.order);
});

In the HTML, when clicking on the confirm button, a modal is launched with a button leading back to home page:

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
  **console.log(req.session.order); // Not sure why the req.session.order here still contains the bookedJourney id, should be []**
  if (!req.session.user) {
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    console.log(req.session.order); // Ditto
    res.render('home', { user: req.session.user });
  }
});
```

Comment: Depending upon how you have your session configured, you may need to [save the session data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#sessionsavecallback) after modifying it or the change won't stick for a future request.

Comment: Thank you i'll have a look at the doc in the link, thanks again

Comment: It has worked, thanks a lot, I still do not understand though why after the push the req.session.save() is not needed while after the re-assignment to an empty array it does

Comment: I'm guessing that you're still using the memory based session data store (the default offering).  If so, that's probably because if you modify an object in the store, the is reflected in the memory data store, but if you replace an object, that won't be copied into the actual store until you do `.save()`.  If you were using a database-back store, likely both examples would have problems.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. I used the default data store indeed, and you're right, probably due to the fact I guess am altering the object by re-assigning it, I'll try to just pop() and see if it works. tks

Comment: Well, you really out to use the proper `req.session.save()` because if you switch to a "production-ready" session store some time in the future, you don't want to have these type of bugs lying around.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session objects need to saved after you modify them with `req.session.save()`.  When using the default memory store for sessions, you get away with some types of session modification (when modifying, not replacing an embedded object like your array), but when you move to a real production-ready store, even those types of modifications likely won't work properly.

So, after modifying the session, call `req.session.save()`.

Comment: Yes, just realised that req.session.save() is not needed when there is a res.redirect/render etc. But as you said, I added the save() to avoid any random inconvenience in production-mode. Thank you.